# Subdocuments pagination in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, pagination, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose 3.6 and my (simplified) schemas look like this

```
var commentSchema = new Schema({
    created: Date  
});

var userSchema = new Schema({
    comments    : [commentSchema],
});
```

I'd like to paginate the comments, so that if I have a user with 25 comments the pages would divide into:

```
page 1: comments 15-24
page 2: comments 5-14
page 3: comments 0-4
page 4: empty
page 5: empty
...
```

This is what I've tried

```
this.findById(user_id, {
        comments: {
            $slice: [-comment_page_index * comments_per_page, comments_per_page]
        }
    }, function(err, user) {
        //...
});
```

While that seemed to be working at first, I was disappointed to find out that the `$slice` operator cuts off the index given when it hits the collection bounds.

So what I get instead is

```
page 1: comments 15-24
page 2: comments 5-14
page 3: comments 0-9
page 4: comments 0-9
page 5: comments 0-9
...
```

A better options here would probably to combine the `sort`, `skip` and `limit` functions, but while I know how to use them on a regular collection, I have to clue on how to apply them to a subdocument. Any thoughs?

Comment: probably it's best not to embed all the comments in the user - an active user will keep the document growing indefinitely which is not a good idea for performance.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I will consider it. Anyway I'd like to know whether there exist a way of paginating subdocuments, without refactoring the whole structure

Comment: you could use aggregation framework - $unwind the array of subdocuments and then use $sort and $limit.

Comment: That seems like the way to go. If you'd like to make an example and put it in an answer I would be grateful :) In any case I'll try by myself

Answer (score 0):

If it's find all or related to displaying, pagination would be something like the code below. The code is just an example:

```
findAll: async function (req, res) {
    var responseObj = {};
    try {
        var responseObj = {};
        var queryArray = [];
        var finalAnswer = [];

        var loggedinUser = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id)
        var auser = await user.findOne({ _id: loggedinUser })
        var places = auser.placesUnderIt;
        for (i of places) {
             var singlePlaceId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(i);
             var singlePlaceData = await place.findOne({ _id: singlePlaceId })
             var list = singlePlaceData.controlledStore;
                    for (k of list) {
                        finalAnswer.push(k);
                    }

                }
             queryArray.push({ _id: { $in: finalAnswer} });
        var query = {
                $and: queryArray
            }

        responseObj.count = await store.countDocuments(query);
        responseObj.data = await store.find(query)
            .populate('ownerId', ["firstName", "lastName", "phoneNumber", "email", "personalDetails"])
            .populate('businesses')
            .limit(parseInt(req.query.limit))
            .skip(parseInt(req.query.skip));

        var data = responseObj.data;
        return res.send(responseObj);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.send('Error');
    }
}
```