# How to limit the number of elements in embedded array in one mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I have the following mongo document representing website and links found on it.

```
 {"website":
     "id":"123456",
     "links":[
                 "link1","link2","link3",..."link1000"
                ]
 }
```

and I want to return a  limited number of links from that specific document found by id, in order to support pagination, e.g. page=1, limit=100 should return first 100 links. 
I tried something like this, but it doesn't work. Is there any way I can limit the number of subdocuments?

```
 String query="{'website.id:'"+id+"'}";
 String fields="{links:1}";
 DBCursor dbCursor=this.getCollection(crawlersCollection)
      .find(this.query(query),this.query(fields)).skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

The other approach I tried is to use $slice

```
 String fields="{'links':{'$slice':["+skip+","+limit+"]}}";
```

but this doesn't work well, because it's not very useful for pagination. For example, if I have 43 links, page=2 with limit=100 will return 43 results, so I have to check the number of links before creating a  query.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get paginated/sliced data of subdocument array in mongo collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157823/how-to-get-paginated-sliced-data-of-subdocument-array-in-mongo-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach would be to use the `$slice` operator. To facilitate pagination you would have to change your method of determining "skip" and "limit".

For example, you could derive the "skip" value from page * limit, e.g. page 2 * limit 10 = skip 20. Then using the slice operator should work fine. If you're "skip" value goes beyond the array length then you'll get back an empty array in your results

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I made a mistake to pass the page number instead of skip value, and I always got a wrong results.